# AttributeError on Mocked Class in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, attributeerror

I am using mockito to unit test a program in Python. I have a class like:

```
import boto3
import datetime

class Cache:

    def __init__(self):
        client = boto3.resource('s3')
        self.bucket_name = 'name'
        self.bucket = client.Bucket(self.bucket_name)

    def setup_cache(self, cache_file='cache.csv', cache_filepath='cache'):
        cache_object = self.bucket.Object(cache_file)

        if cache_object.last_modified < datetime.datetime.now():
            self.bucket.download_file(cache_filepath, cache_file)
        else:
            print('Cache already up to date')


def main():
    cache = Cache()
    cache.setup_cache()
```

And the test code I am getting stuck on is this:

```
from mockito import mock, when
import datetime
import boto3

import mock_cache

class TestMockCache:

    def test_last_mod(self):

        mock_client = mock()
        when(boto3).resource('s3').thenReturn(mock_client)

        mock_bucket = mock()
        when(mock_client).Bucket('name').thenReturn(mock_bucket)

        mock_bucket.last_modified = datetime.datetime.now()

        mock_cache.main()
```

When running pytest on the unit test, I am getting thrown this attribute error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'last_modified'
```

From the documentation it looked like I could assign 'cache_mock.last_modified' like this. However, I also tried:

```
when(cache_mock).last_modified.thenReturn(test_date)
```

and got:

```
AttributeError: 'StubbedInvocation' object has no attribute 'thenReturn'
```

Which I don't fully understand, but assume that means a mockito mock() object can't have multiple return values?

Any help with this would be appreciated. I feel like I am misunderstanding something fundamental about either how mockito's mock works or mocking in general.

Comment: Could you produce the real time code example to recreate the issue? Also please specify the some_cache_library you are trying to use?

Comment: @Roxy Edited the code. 'some_cache_library' was just a made up thing. The real library in play here is boto3

Comment: Expected the same. I have updated the answer below. Let me know if you still could not resolve it.

Comment: Were you able to get through with the solution below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `patch` from the `Mock` can be used to mock the `client` from `boto3`. Do not have to return anything from the client, as it is being mocked on the whole.

e.g.:

```
from folder.file import your_func
from unittest.mock import patch

class TestSomething(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("botocore.client.BaseClient._make_api_call")
    def test_something(self, _mock_client_boto3):
        your_func()
        .. do something
```

In case you want to return something from the client, it could be achieved by specifying the `return_value` in the patch as shown below:

```
from folder.file import your_func
from unittest.mock import patch

class TestSomething(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("botocore.client.BaseClient._make_api_call", return_value=None)
    def test_something(self, _mock_client_boto3):
        your_func()
        .. do something
```

Comment: That's not a good answer as it a) doesn't use `mockito` and b) patches a *private* method.  A user should mock out the exact methods she uses.  How should I know that `_make_api_call` is the correct one here now or in the future?